# Is there a less computationally expensive method to replace names in a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, performance, indexing, list-comprehension

I want to add '-PD' to only a subset of names that meet a certain condition in a big dataframe (~6 million rows).

I made a bool list of the names that I want to change:

```
bool_list = df_geo_clean_tag['index'].isin(lessorequalto0_ids)
```

and then I looped over the dataframe where bool_list was true to find the indexes where the name should be replaced:

```
for row in range(len(df_geo_clean_tag)):
    if bool_list[row] == True:
        name = df_geo_clean_tag.iloc[row, 0]
        df_geo_clean_tag.iloc[row, 0] = name + '-PD'
```

but this is taking an extremely long time (currently been waiting over an hour).
Is there a less computationally expensive way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should much faster than the loop:

```py
df_geo_clean_tag.loc[bool_list, df.columns[0]] += '-PD'
```

This code `df_geo_clean_tag` filter the lines by `bool_list` and then extract the first column before and modifying the filtered strings.